# VB.NET: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, outofrangeexception

Im attempting to make a multi-threaded socket program that communicates via TCP. I have followed [this tutorial](http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_multithreaded_Socket_programming.htm) but get the following error.

P.S Im new at network programming

**Here is the Stack Trace:**

```
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Multi_TCP_Server.Module1.handleClinet.doChat() in \Multi-TCP_Server\Module1.vb:line 57
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**Here is Server code:** (Multi-TCP_Server.vb)

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim LocalAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10")
    Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(LocalAddr, 8888)
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Dim counter As Integer

    serverSocket.Start()
    msg("Server Started")
    counter = 0
    While (True)
        counter += 1
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
        msg("Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!")
        Dim client As New handleClinet
        client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter))
    End While

    clientSocket.Close()
    serverSocket.Stop()
    msg("exit")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub msg(ByVal mesg As String)
    mesg.Trim()
    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + mesg)
End Sub

Public Class handleClinet
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Dim clNo As String
    Public Sub startClient(ByVal inClientSocket As TcpClient,
    ByVal clineNo As String)
        Me.clientSocket = inClientSocket
        Me.clNo = clineNo
        Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf doChat)
        ctThread.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub doChat()
        Dim requestCount As Integer
        Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
        Dim dataFromClient As String
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
        Dim serverResponse As String
        Dim rCount As String
        requestCount = 0

        While (True)
            ' Try
            requestCount = requestCount + 1
                Dim networkStream As NetworkStream =
                        clientSocket.GetStream()
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
                dataFromClient =
            dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
                msg("From client-" + clNo + dataFromClient)
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount)
                serverResponse = "Server to clinet(" + clNo + ") " + rCount
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                networkStream.Flush()
                msg(serverResponse)
            'Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            'End Try

        End While

    End Sub
End Class
End Module
```

**And Here is the Client Code:** (Multi-TCP_Client.vb)

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
Dim clientSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
Dim serverStream As NetworkStream


Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Button1.Click
    Dim serverStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
    Dim buffSize As Integer
    Dim outStream As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message from Client")
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 32, outStream.Length)
    'serverStream.Flush()

    Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
    buffSize = inStream.Length
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)
    Dim returndata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
    msg("Data from Server : " + returndata)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object,
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    msg("Client Started")
    Try
        clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.10", 8888)
        ConnectionStatusLbl.Text = "Server Connected..."
    Catch ex As Exception
        ConnectionStatusLbl.Text = "Unable to connect."
    End Try
End Sub

Sub msg(ByVal mesg As String)
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg
End Sub
End Class
```

All help and ideas are appreciated.
Thanks :)

EDIT: [Here](http://pastebin.com/8eMeH1CU) is the Stack Trace from Multi-TCP_Client.vb

Comment: It's good that you gave us the StackTrace so that we know where the error occurs, but we need the actual error message aswell so that we'll get a hunch of what's actually wrong.

Comment: Also, instead of constantly calling `clientSocket.GetStream()` and waste (rather little, but still) resources, declare the variable _**before**_ the loop.

Comment: @VisualVincent The Error is the first part of the stack trace?

at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Multi_TCP_Server.Module1.handleClinet.doChat() in \Multi-TCP_Server\Module1.vb:line 57

Comment: I know _where_ the error is, but I asked for the error _**message**_. That is, _**what**_ it says went wrong.

Comment: In `NetworkStream.Read()` the last parameter should be `bytesFrom.Length` and _**not**_ `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`. `CInt()` is not needed since they both already are integers.

Comment: Ok that seems to have solved the problem...sort of. Now in Multi-TCP_Client.vb im getting this error on line 12. Ill add the stack trace to the Post

{"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: offset"}

Comment: No need for the StackTrace this time, line 12 is easy to find.

Comment: The same applies there. You should never use `ClientSend-/ReceiveBufferSize` since they're not relevant to the data you're receiving. The final parameter of `NetworkStream.Read()` and `Write()` should _**at most**_ be the length of the byte array you pass as the first parameter.

Comment: `buffSize = inStream.Length` should solve your problem.

Comment: @VisualVincent
This error occurs on line 12 now:

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: offset

Comment: That's the same as before. Did you change the clientside like I told you to? If so, try removing the `serverStream.Flush()` call.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes I have changed the client side. I have updated the Client Code in the post

Comment: Hmm... It looks alright, but I'll have to try it out to know for sure. I don't have access to an IDE right now, but I will in about an hour.

Comment: @visual vincent No problem

Comment: Hi! I am so sorry! I got busy and forgot about this. I'm testing your code now.

Comment: Ah, of course. I missed that when I was looking from my phone! This line, in the client: `serverStream.Write(outStream, 32, outStream.Length)` should be: `serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)`.

Comment: The second parameter of `Write()` (called `offset`) indicates from where in the byte array you want to start sending data. It should be `0` to start from the beginning of the array. -- This also means that the last parameter must be `total length - offset` or smaller.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you very much! It all seems to be working now :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!